# Change my executable icon

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to changing default icons on c++ console applications. But recently, I have been wanting to know how it is accomplished. I managed to save an .ico file and when I build my application in Release mode I open it and I see the new image show up when my window is running and then a tiny icon showing up in the top left hand of the screen, and seeing that made me very happy.

[image]

[image]

But I wanted to know how can I change the image of my executable file so that it is consistent with my program?

From this...

[image]

To this...

[image]

Can anyone help me figure out what the steps are to change the default executable icon to the one I want? Many thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new file to the existing projekt and select as file type
"Symbol (ico)" in the "Resource" category.
Draw it, save it, compile again, finished.
Windows will automatically display the icon with the lowest ID (if any).
If there is only one icon, it can be only that one...

edit: You should make different sizes (16x16, 32x32, 64x64 etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your help. You wouldn't happen to know where could I find the place to edit the console application's name would you? Because when I start up my application it shows the full path to the file and I just want it to read the tittle of the application

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: This does not work for me, plus drawing it in Visual Studio is a pain and not practical at all. Is there a way to add my existing .ico file and have the .exe use it?